# What's wrong with my java code? (parsing error)

Tags: java, class, identifier

```
public class 1127 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        binomial();
    }

    public static double binomial(int N, int k, double p)
    {
        if (N == 0 && k ==0) return 1.0;
        if (N < 0 || k < 0) return 0.0;
        return (1.0 - p)*binomial(N-1, k, p) + p*binomial(N-1, k-1, p);
    }
}
```

> /Volumes/2/Learn_Algorithms/chapter one/1127.java:13: reached end of
>   file while parsing    }}
>                                                     SUBNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNUL
>
> ^
>   15 Errors

This is my first time writing Java code and I have a few questions.

1. what does the "reached end of file while parsing" mean?

I don't think I missed any '{' or '}'

2. Then how about those series of SUBNULNULNUL...?
3. How did it calculate out 15 ERRORS?

Comment: To start with 1127 isn't a valid name for a class

Comment: There is no no-arg overload of your binomial method `binomial`. so `binomial();` will generate another compile time error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name `1127` is not a valid name for a class.

A class name is an [identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) and must start with a letter; identifiers cannot start with a digit.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what does those tailing SUBNULNUL mean btw?

Comment: What editor did you use to type in this code? Maybe there are strange characters in your source file. Use a plain text editor, not a word processor to edit your code.

Answer (score 1):

you must have arguments for calling your function in main:

```
binomial(a,b,c);
```

cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's another compiling problem

Comment: Cheers mate, programming for life! :D (I'm a newbie too :P )

Answer (score 1):

Don't start a class name with a number/integer. A class name should be a valid identifier in Java. Look at here about the rules of [identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbuk/index.html).